# How to open default Mail App Inbox from within my Android app?

Tags: android, email

My Android 4+ app offers the user the possibility to setup a new user account for a web service. Once the user has sent the registration data, the new account is created and needs to be confirmed by clicking on a link which is sent to the user's e-mail address.

To make the registration as smooth as possible I would like to offer a "Go to your mail inbox" button once the data was submitted.

In iOS I can use the `message://` URL scheme to do this. When my app calls such an URL iOS automatically switches to the Mail app.

How can this be done on Android?

Of course, I know about `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)...` to create and send a new mail but this is not what I am looking for. The user should not send an e-mail but check his inbox for new emails.

**EDIT:**

This is not a duplicate of the linked question since this is not about starting a specific app (e.g. "com.google.android.gm") but the systems default mail app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

---

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL):

> Used with ACTION_MAIN to launch the email application. The activity
>   should be able to send and receive email.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` like below:

```
final Intent emailLauncher = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
emailLauncher.setType("message/rfc822");
try{
       startActivity(emailLauncher);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){

}
```